# How to get Auto Generated ID from SQL Table when multiple users working simultaneously

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Am creating a SQL Database for multiple users(Roughly 100 user), each records having nearly 15 fields in it.. In which the ID field is auto incremented...

Whenever a person Inserting a record to the database, it has to show "auto incremented ID" for that particular person, For this am using this code

```
PreparedStatement ppstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ppstmt.execute(sql,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = ppstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
long key = 0;
if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
    key = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

As of now its working fine but **my doubt is when multiple users inserting the record at the same time, whether it will corresponding auto generated ID to each person..?**

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And how is the ID generated?

Comment: Am using Oracle database only...

Comment: So how is the ID generated in the database?

Comment: What is the value of `sql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is SQL, so the database vendor is irrelevant, and he has clearly stated the keys are auto-incremented.

Comment: @ShaneCoder : 'sql' is inserting operation comment

Comment: @ejp: "auto-increments" are **highly** DBMS specific so the vendor is far from being "irrelevant". Oracle only added a feature like that in 12c. Before that, this had to be done using a trigger and sequences. And "SQL" does not define the semantics on how JDBC retrieves these generated values.

Answer (score 0):

The statement will work correctly. The generated key returned will be the key generated by that execution of that statement for that user. These are SQL-defined semantics. Any implementation where it didn't work would be broken.

NB the result set cannot be null at the point you're testing it.

Comment: My doubt is whether it will work for multiple users, For example when three users inserting records at the same time (even milliseconds also equal), whether they will get auto generated ID for respective operation?

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged oracle, so here is oracle's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/jdbcvers.htm#JJDBC28099) on how retrieving generated keys works. A key piece of information is:

> Auto-generated keys are implemented using the DML returning clause.

So it is worth looking at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2171131) on how the returning clause works.
As you can see, this is guaranteed to return only data relevant to the just executed statement.

I would also like to point out that your use of a PreparedStatement is wrong. Once you have created the PreparedStatement from

```
PreparedStatement ppstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

The next call should be to [ppstmt.execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29) followed by [ppstmt.getGeneratedKeys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29).